# iOS Enterprise update integration

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ios-enterprise

**the case:** I'm using iOS Enterprise Program for Ionic 2 app. One of issues for such distribution type was in supporting update flow. To solve this, we created simple JSON on server side to check available update. When update is available, user sees alert with suggestion to update app or exit.

**app.component.ts**

```
    iosUpdateCheck() {
        this.http.get(`${this.config.iosEnterpriseEndpoint}latest.json`).map(res =>
          <{version: string}>res.json()).subscribe((res) => {

          if (res.version !== this.config.appVersionNumber) {
            this.message.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'Update is available!',
              message: 'Please, update your terminal to proceed',
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Update',
                  handler: () => {
                    console.log(this.TAG + 'iosUpdateCheck: update clicked');
//I tried just href also
                     window.window.open(`<a href=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=${this.config.iosEnterpriseEndpoint}manifest.plist />`,'_system');
                  }
                },
                {
                  text: 'Exit',
                  role: 'cancel',
                  handler: () => {
                    console.log(this.TAG + 'iosUpdateCheck: exit clicked');
                    this.platform.exitApp();
                  }
                },
              ]
            }).present();
          }
        });
      }
```

I also added in `config.xml` `<allow-intent href="itms-services:*"/>` but still getting same error(sorry for screenshot, it's impossible to copy error link in Safari): 
[image]
If I will use just a link it works fine but does not correspond to the objectives pursued.

Comment: Hey, did you find a Solution. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this ionic-native plugin might help you: [Ionic Native Market plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/market/).

**Installation:**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-market
npm install --save @ionic-native/market
```

And don't for get to add it to your `app.module`.

**Usage:**

```
import { Market } from '@ionic-native/market';
constructor(private market: Market) { }

this.market.open('your.package.name');
```